# Async calls never returns in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I am return a list which basically calls the two async operations:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult List(DataSourceRequest command, ProductListModel model)
{
    var categories = _productService.GetAllProducts(model.SearchProductName,
        command.Page - 1, command.PageSize);

    var gridModel = new DataSourceResult
    {
        Data = categories.Select(async x =>
        {
            var productModel = x.ToModel();
            var manufacturer = await _manufacturerService.GetManufacturerById(x.ManufacturerId);
            var category = await _categoryService.GetCategoryById(x.CategoryId);

            productModel.Category = category.Name;
            productModel.Manufacturer = manufacturer.Name;
            return productModel;
        }),
        Total = categories.TotalCount
    };
    return Json(gridModel);
}
```

It is an ajax request (from client side) but on front-end it never returns. Is there any a deadlock ?

Comment: How are you `await`ing calls when not inside a method that (a) is not marked as `async` and (b) does not return `Task<ActionResult>`?

Comment: Because its a lamda expression. If i marke the method `async Task<ActionResult>` the compiler reports that my method lacks `await` operator. Even if ii put it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Cool, I just saw the `async` delegate. That's the problem by the looks of it. Is `Data` a `Task<T>` where `T` is the `x.ToModel()` type?

Comment: no, Data = IEnumberable while ToModel() is a ViewModel i.e ProductModel()

Comment: Pretty sure it will be an `IEnumerable<Task>` because of the async delegate passed to `.Select()`. This means that it will not be waiting for the task to complete. If you `await` the `categories.Select()` call by wrapping in a `Task.WhenAll()`, mark the action as `async` and return `Task<ActionResult>`, I believe this should solve your problem

Comment: Yes. Are you ponting Task.WheAll() ?

Comment: i used `Task.WhenAll()` but i got an exception so.. `A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`

Comment: You need to `await` it and make the controller action async

Comment: i did that too. Maybe its a dbcontext issue, as its not thread safe!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building up my answer from several comments and @usr's answer:

- `Data` in the code above is actually `IEnumerable<Task<ProductModel>>`, not `IEnumerable<ProductModel>`. This is because the lambda passed to `Select` is `async`.
- Most likely, the JSON serializer is going over this structure and enumerating the properties on the `Task<ProductModel>` instances, including `Result`.

I explain on my blog [why accessing `Result` will cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) in this case. In a nutshell, it's because the `async` lambda will attempt to resume execution on the ASP.NET request context after its `await`. However, the ASP.NET request context is blocked on the call to `Result`, locking a thread inside that request context until the `Task<T>` completes. Since the `async` lambda cannot resume, it cannot complete that task. So both things are waiting for each other, and you get a classic deadlock.

There are some suggestions to use `await Task.WhenAll`, which I would normally agree with. However, in this case you're using Entity Framework and got this error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed.

This is because EF cannot perform multiple asynchronous calls concurrently within the same db context. There are a couple ways around this; one is to use multiple db contexts (essentially multiple connections) to do the calls concurrently. IMO a simpler way is to make the asynchronous calls sequentially instead of concurrently:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> List(DataSourceRequest command, ProductListModel model)
{
  var categories = _productService.GetAllProducts(model.SearchProductName,
      command.Page - 1, command.PageSize);

  var data = new List<ProductModel>();
  foreach (var x in categories)
  {
    var productModel = x.ToModel();
    var manufacturer = await _manufacturerService.GetManufacturerById(x.ManufacturerId);
    var category = await _categoryService.GetCategoryById(x.CategoryId);

    productModel.Category = category.Name;
    productModel.Manufacturer = manufacturer.Name;
    data.Add(productModel);
  }

  var gridModel = new DataSourceResult
  {
    Data = data,
    Total = categories.TotalCount
  };
  return Json(gridModel);
}
```

Comment: Async LINQ would be a nice thing to have here.

Comment: Great summary Stephen :)

Answer (score 2):

The way to debug is is to pause the debugger during the hang. There you will find that some serializer is blocking on `Task.Result` or similar.

You fill the `Data` property with a `IEnumerable<Task>`. The serializer probably calls `Result` at some point and that's the classic ASP.NET deadlock. You probably should wrap the `Select` call with `await Task.WhenAll(x.Select(...))`.

And even then it might be unsafe to concurrently run those lambdas.